# How can I set JENKINS_HOME variable when Jenkins is running via Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I deployed my Jenkins with Tomcat and it's running perfect. Now I've noticed that **Jenkins is currently installed on the root user** (/root/.jenkins), BUT **I need to have it installed on a differnt location**, not on root.
I read that I have to move the .jenkins folder to my prefered destination and then have to edit the JENKINS_HOME variable.
The problem is: When I type *env* **there is no JENKINS_HOME** variable, so I can't edit it. **I guess that's because I installed Jenkins using Tomcat?**

***How can I move my jenkins to a new location (different from root) and therefore, if needed, how do I solve the issue with the missing JENKINS_HOME variable?***

Answer (score 0):

You can define JENKINS_HOME variable in the system variables , once you will restart the jenkins via tomcat or any other way, the jenkins will pickup the environment variable and unload the files on new jenkins_home